# Multi-threaded memoisation in Rust

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust

I am developing an algorithm in Rust that I want to multi-thread. The nature of the algorithm is that it produces solutions to overlapping subproblems, hence why I am looking for a way to achieve multi-threaded memoisation.

An implementation of (single-threaded) memoisation is presented by Pritchard in [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/on-memoization-291fd1dd924).

I would like to have this functionality extended such that:

1. Whenever the underlying function must be invoked, *including recursively*, the result is evaluated asynchronously on a new thread.
2. Continuing on from the previous point, suppose we have some memoised function `f`, and `f(x)` that needs to recursively invoke `f(x1)`, `f(x2)`, … `f(xn)`. It should be possible for all of these recursive invocations to be evaluated concurrently on separate threads.
3. If the memoised function is called on an input whose result is currently being evaluated, the current thread should block on this thread, and somehow obtain the result after it is released. This ensures that we don't end up with multiple threads attempting to evaluate the same result.
4. There is a means of forcing `f(x)` to be evaluated and cached (if it isn't already) without blocking the current thread. This allows the programmer to preemptively begin the evaluation of a result on a particular value that they know will be (or is likely to be) needed later.

Comment: Please provide a [reprex]. What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: It sounds complicated enough that you're likely to completely undo the benefits of parallelism because of the overhead of data sharing.

Comment: Why do you think this should be parallel? What is the point of spawning a new thread and immediately blocking on it? The point of parallelism is to continue working on something else while you wait for the result of work on another thread. How much work can this recursive function really do while it is waiting for the `n-1`th value to be calculated?

Comment: @Coder-256 I probably didn't make this clear enough in my question, but there is a lot of *breadth* in the recursive invocations as well as depth. I don't know what the equivalent would be in Rust, but imagine in JavaScript, `f(x)` calls `Promise.all([f(x1), f(x2), … f(xn)])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is by storing a `HashMap`, where the key is the paramaters to `f` and the value is the receiver of a oneshot message containing the result. Then for any value that you need:

- If there is already a receiver in the map, await it.
- Otherwise, spawn a future to start calculating the result, and store the receiver in the map.

Here is a very contrived example that took way longer than it should have, but successfully runs ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=40c47d87c323cc1870aa6bbc77f45556)):

```rust
use futures::{
    future::{self, BoxFuture},
    prelude::*,
    ready,
};
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    pin::Pin,
    sync::Arc,
    task::{Context, Poll},
};
use tokio::sync::{oneshot, Mutex};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct MemoInput(usize);

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct MemoReturn(usize);

/// This is necessary in order to make a concrete type for the `HashMap`.
struct OneshotReceiverUnwrap<T>(oneshot::Receiver<T>);

impl<T> Future for OneshotReceiverUnwrap<T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        // Don't worry too much about this part
        Poll::Ready(ready!(Pin::new(&mut self.0).poll(cx)).unwrap())
    }
}

type MemoMap = Mutex<HashMap<MemoInput, future::Shared<OneshotReceiverUnwrap<MemoReturn>>>>;

/// Compute (2^n)-1, super inefficiently.
fn compute(map: Arc<MemoMap>, x: MemoInput) -> BoxFuture<'static, MemoReturn> {
    async move {
        // First, get all dependencies.
        let dependencies: Vec<MemoReturn> = future::join_all({
            let map2 = map.clone();
            let mut map_lock = map.lock().await;

            // This is an iterator of futures that resolve to the results of the
            // dependencies.
            (0..x.0).map(move |i| {
                let key = MemoInput(i);
                let key2 = key.clone();

                (*map_lock)
                    .entry(key)
                    .or_insert_with(|| {
                        // If the value is not currently being calculated (ie.
                        // is not in the map), start calculating it
                        let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel();
                        let map3 = map2.clone();
                        tokio::spawn(async move {
                            // Compute the value, then send it to the receiver
                            // that we put in the map. This will awake all
                            // threads that were awaiting it.
                            tx.send(compute(map3, key2).await).unwrap();
                        });
                        // Return a shared future so that multiple threads at a
                        // time can await it
                        OneshotReceiverUnwrap(rx).shared()
                    })
                    .clone() // Clone one instance of the shared future for us
            })
        })
        .await;

        // At this point, all dependencies have been resolved!

        let result = dependencies.iter().map(|r| r.0).sum::<usize>() + x.0;
        MemoReturn(result)
    }
    .boxed() // Box in order to prevent a recursive type
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let map = Arc::new(MemoMap::default());
    let result = compute(map, MemoInput(10)).await.0;
    println!("{}", result); // 1023
}
```

Note: this could certainly be better optimized, this is just a POC example.